# reinstalling 16.04

Tags: reinstall

this question has probably been asked and answered many times. I am new to ubuntu and still in the early stages of learning. I have 16.04 installed on my desktop ssd with the home folder on a hdd. I would like to know if it is possible to reinstall the os and keep the home folder and the route the home folder intact? if it is, how do I do it? 
Thanks for all your help and patience with this.
Richard